# Flutter: Same object, same runtimeType but runtimeType== other.runtimeType is false

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I encountered a strange issue during my tests.
I'm trying to verify a function call - to my logger:

```
 verify(() => logger.i(WorkflowButtonClicked(value: true))).called(1);
```

The test runs, and there is a call:

```
    logger.i(new WorkflowButtonClicked(value: true));
```

WorkflowButtonClicked class extends Equatable, but for some reason, the verify is false.
I checked the code on Equatable class and saw that:

```
 @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is Equatable &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          equals(props, other.props);
```

and the problem is that runtimeType == other.runtimeType is false,
and I can't understand why, because if the String representation of runtimeType is the same.
I tried overriding the runttimeType:

```
  Type get runtimeType {
    return WorkflowButtonClicked;
  }
```

but the "==" was still false;
Only if I override the runtimeType with return "int" it works for some strange reaseon.
Don't know how to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to create a reproducible example?  Are you sure that you don't have multiple classes both named `WorkflowButtonClicked`, possibly from importing the same `.dart` file with inconsistent capitalization?

Comment: Ok you gave me an idea, i will reply with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out what happened, the problem was the import:

bad:
import '../models/logger/log_types/workflow_button_clicked.dart';

good:
import 'package:APP/models/logger/log_types/workflow_button_clicked.dart';

Not sure why, but it solved it.

Comment: Are you on Windows?  Were you importing the file with a relative path everywhere in your project, or were you using a relative import in some places and a package-path in others?  This still smells like something caused by inconsistent path capitalization somewhere.

Comment: macOS, I probably preseed the first import option

Comment: macOS with a case-insensitive filesystem, I presume...